# Open set in point set topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology and $B=[1,2] \cup [3,4]$. Is $[1,2]$ open in $B$? The answer is yes because $[1,2] \cup [3,4] \cap (1/2, 5/2)$. I don't understand the answer and reasoning. Can someone please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the relative/subspace topology is this: If $X$ is a topological space and $B$ is a subset of $X$, we say that a set $A\subseteq B$ is open in $B$ if there is some $U$ open in $X$ with $A=B\cap U$.

In metric spaces, this is even more intuitive. In your example in particular, note that every point of $[1,2]$ is less than $1$ away from $\frac12,$ and that there are no other points of $B$ that are less than $1$ away from $\frac12.$ Hence, $[1,2]$ is in fact open in $B,$ even though it isn't open in $\Bbb R$.

Another way to see this: $[3,4]$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, so closed in $B,$ and so $[1,2]=B\setminus[3,4]$ is open in $B$.

**Upshot**: All the sets that used to be open/closed will still be open/closed in the relative topology, but we may also get some new ones that weren't open/closed before.

Comment: By your reasoning for the second method you are implying that something that is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ is also closed in $B$  than wouldn't $[1,2]$ be closed in $B$ because its closed in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, indeed! It is both closed and open in $B$.